# Sharing controllers in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I have two date-pickers, one text field and a button in one form as below:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Date End </label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <p class="input-group" ng-controller="datePickerCtrl">
                <input type="text" name="endDate" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>
                </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Staff </label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="staff.name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Close">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="userClickedCancel()">Filter</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                </div>
```

As can be seen, each date-picker has the same controller: `datePickerCtrl`. I would like to have one controller attached to the whole form that will utilise the dates returned by the date-pickers and the text field. However, I'm not sure how to do it since both date-pickers are returning the date as `ng-model=dt`.

I do not want to copy paste the `datePickerCtrl` code in multiple places with a different variable to `dt` in each instance. I also don't want to create one controller and copy the `datePickerCtrl` into it since I would like to keep the code for date-picker separate. What's the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: why can't you place all the date picker models in an array ?